# React Native cannot run stacktrace

Tags: java, android, macos, react-native

I am trying to get a test project up and running with React Native on a Mac (osx 10.12). If I run:

`react-native run-android --stacktrace`

I get the following error:

`error: unknown option '--stacktrace'`

I have installed:

- Node Watchman
- Flow
- Java JDK
- Android SDK
- React Native CLI
- Genymotion

When I run the command the emulator is running.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Many thanks in advance.

**Edit** 
After run `gradlew  installDebug --stacktrace` I got this response:

```
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
07:20:21 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
07:20:21 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
07:20:21 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /Users/kristian/Documents/Work/Roche/roche-mobile-app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: returning
07:20:21 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:20:22 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:20:22 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `--stacktrace` suggestion isn't output by the `react-native run-android` command, it comes from one of the commands it runs. Here's how to run it with the `--stacktrace` option. Read further for an explanation.

```
cd android && ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace
```

`react-native run-android` actually runs `cd android && ./gradlew installDebug` as you can see in the following lines outputted by `react-native run-android`

```
Running /Users/upside/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 0111474880b8a726 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
```

So, if you want to run with the `--stacktrace` option, you'll need to run `cd android && ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace`

Once you've figured out your problem, you should go back to using `react-native run-android` as the script probably runs a lot more commands as well.