# React-native: Build failed with an exception, unexpected token: keyword (default)

Tags: debugging, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm trying to build react-native android apk using,

> ./gradlew assembleRelease

Got the below error,

> **Unexpected token: keyword (default)**
>
> :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
>   :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 52.893 secs.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
>   Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

How can I know from which file this error came "Unexpected token: keyword (default)"

Is there a way to find detailed report of where the JS failed.

Comment: Go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022166/react-native-cannot-run-stacktrace

Comment: Already tried --stacktrace, but with no help. It is giving Java trace of app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets which is not helpful. I actually want to know which file and line in javascript this "unexpected token: keyword (default)" occurs, surely somewhere in the sourcetcode or node_modules keyword default is causing issue (propably es6) but unable to find it.

Comment: Then please add your code where you are getting this error because from the information you provided no one can find the reason of error